# How to pass --enable-preview in org.graalvm.buildtools.native plugin?

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I would like to configure the Gradle native plugin in a way that it will have `--enable-preview` enabled.

When I try to add those properties to `compileOptions` I get access violation:

[image: Cannot access 'compileOptions': it is protected/protected and package/ for synthetic extension in '']

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [plugin docs](https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/guides/use-native-image-gradle-plugin/) suggest using `buildArgs`

Comment: @peterz you can convert it to an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @peterz:

```kotlin
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        all {
            jvmArgs("--enable-preview")
        }
    }
}
```